# AngularJS Scope Function Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, scope, angularjs-scope

I have an angularjs controller. I added a function to it's scope, since this function is called from the html.

```
$scope.search = function() {
    //do something
};
```

But I need to call this function from inside my controller too.
I can do this by either calling

```
$scope.search();
```

or

```
this.search();
```

Both work. It's clear form me that it works, calling on the `$scope`, but why does it work calling on `this`? As far as I understand, the `$scope` is a dedicated object.
Also, what's the preferred way of calling the function from within the controller?

Comment: Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: these **are not equivalent**, unless there is some other code which you are not showing that makes them equivalent.

Comment: The link posted by salix answers my question. I called `this.search()` from within my scope function. Therefore `this` referred to `$scope` and not to my controller.